# I wanted to remove particular pattern from a string in tcl

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, grep, tcl

hreset_error_status_t2_reg1
htrans_flag_t1_reg2
hsize_flag_error_reg
check_hwdata_reg

I had to write a Tcl script using regex I have to remove error_status, *flag*, *flag_error, and check* in the following strings. It has to search the following keywords in the file and have to remove the mentioned keywords in a string.

Comment: Is that the string you start with? What string do you want to end up with? Be clear: write it out in full.

Comment: These are basically string in a file
1)hreset_error_status_t2_reg1 
2)htrans_flag_t1_reg2 
3)hsize_flag_error_reg 
4)check_hwdata_reg

I wanted it to printed in this manner,
1)hreset_t2_reg1 
2)htrans_t1_reg2 
3)hsize_reg 
4)hwdata_reg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all those patterns from a string, use `regsub -all`.   If you don't need to use the power of regular expressions, then `string map` works well too.

```
set my_str "hreset_error_status_t2_reg1 htrans_flag_t1_reg2 hsize_flag_error_reg check_hwdata_reg"
set my_regex {error_status_|flag_(error_)?|check_}
regsub -all $my_regex $my_str ""
  --> hreset_t2_reg1 htrans_t1_reg2 hsize_reg hwdata_reg
```

or

```
set my_map {
   error_status_  ""
   flag_error_    ""
   flag_          ""
   check_         ""
}
string map $my_map $my_str
   --> hreset_t2_reg1 htrans_t1_reg2 hsize_reg hwdata_reg
```

Note that I put `flag_error_` before `flag_` in `$my_map` so that only the `flag_` characters in `flag_error` weren't removed.